# Merge event fires after delete triggers for the losing records and before update triggers for the winning record only?

Tags: apex, trigger

Merge event fires after delete triggers for the losing records and before update triggers for the winning record only - is this correct ?

Are there other before/after events for which trigger is fired ?

Answer (score 3):

Merge events do not fire their own trigger events. Instead, they fire delete and update events as follows:
Deletion of losing records

- A single merge operation fires a single delete event for all records
  that are deleted in the merge. To determine which records were
  deleted as a result of a merge operation use the MasterRecordId field
  in Trigger.old. When a record is deleted after losing a merge
  operation, its MasterRecordId field is set to the ID of the winning
  record. The MasterRecordId field is only set in after delete trigger
  events. If your application requires special handling for deleted
  records that occur as a result of a merge, you need to use the after
  delete trigger event.

Update of the winning record

- A single merge operation fires a single update event for the winning
  record only. Any child records that are reparented as a result of the
  merge operation do not fire triggers.
- For example, if two contacts
  are merged, only the delete and update contact triggers fire. No
  triggers for records related to the contacts, such as accounts or
  opportunities, fire.

The following is the order of events when a merge occurs:

1. The before delete trigger fires.
2. The system deletes the necessary records due to the merge, assigns
   new parent records to the child records, and sets the MasterRecordId
   field on the deleted records.
3. The after delete trigger fires.
4. The system does the specific updates required for the master record.
   Normal update triggers apply.

Source : http://goo.gl/9IZyi

Discussion : http://goo.gl/iMcraj

---

A trigger is Apex code that executes before or after the following types of operations:

1. insert
2. update
3. delete
4. merge
5. upsert
6. undelete